# RF attenuator resistors

Tags: resistors, rf

hi i am trying to find a formula 
to reduce 1 watt 1000mw  to 0.5  watt  500mw RF 
basically cut the rf power in half using an attenuator
which  kind of resistors  would be best for this

has to be on a so239 socket

Comment: What impedance is your rf system?

Comment: High quality rf attenuators use special radial resistors. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: yes 0 db db  or 20 50 ohms

Comment: What frequency is the RF signal at?

Comment: 87 - 108 mhz fm

Comment: Are you looking for the resistors or are you looking for attenuators?  The first part sounds like you want to build an attenuator, then you say it has to be on a S0239 connector which sounds like you just want to buy one.  If you want to buy one, I found piles of them with a quick google.  This site is not for purchase reccommendations.

Comment: looking for resistors  to take the rf power down form 1 watt (1000mw) to 0.5 watt (500mw)

Answer (score 2):

Get a couple of these but one with a female on the BNC end: -

[image]

And one of these (but a 3dB version): -

[image]

Plug them together and that should do the trick.

Comment: @jippie OOps yeah its N to SO239 instead of BNC to SO239. Fixing....

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a 50 ohm system, you're looking to reduce the signal by 3 dB.  You can look up attenuators, but here's one site I like: [radio-electronics.com](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/rf-technology-design/attenuators/attenuator-resistor-values.php).  A typical pi attenuator would have standard value resistors:

```
 signal ----------------/\/\/\/\------------------- 
                  |       18        |              
                  /                 /           
                  \ 300             \ 300          
                  /                 /          
                  |                 |              
 ground -------------------------------------------
```

You need resistors capable of dissipating 1 watt, and the optimal resistor would be a carbon composite resistor.  Carbon comp are non-inductive.  At the frequencies and power level you're working with, you may be OK with an every day resistor from your junk box.

Comment: is that resistor 300 ohms

Comment: i am also looking an output transistor similar to  m 2n4427 witch is a 1watt  but are looking for the 500mw version if anyone could help with a part number

Comment: Yes, 300 ohms and 18 ohms. Regarding the 2N4427, it looks like you want to ask another question because swapping transistors might mean altering the bias too.

Answer (score 0):

For RF circuits one uses non-inductive resistances.
1. If wire wounf twice R ohms resistances are wound in clockwise and other one counter clock wise.
2. If a carbon or metal oxide-(-NO helical groove for resistance value adjustment).. simply changing the thickness of cylindrical coat of resisatnce.
vtingole